# AS400 jt400 get RAM usage

Tags: java, memory, ibm-midrange, ram, jt400

I am just experimenting with the `jt400.jar` to receive system information from an `AS400`.

I figured out how to connect and how to receive values by using the class `SystemStatus` and how to read `SystemValues`. (only need to find an explanation for those values, any hints for me?)

Can anyone tell me, which of the functions in `SystemStatus` delivers me the usage of RAM or a poper way of receiving this information?

```
private static void getSystemStatus() throws AS400SecurityException, ErrorCompletingRequestException,
            InterruptedException, IOException, ObjectDoesNotExistException, RequestNotSupportedException {
        //Connect to AS400
        AS400 as400 = new AS400("myAs400", "myUser", "myPassword");

        //Reading SystemStatus like CPU usage and hdd usage
        SystemStatus systemStatus = new SystemStatus(as400);
        System.out.println(systemStatus.getPercentProcessingUnitUsed());
        System.out.println(systemStatus.getActiveJobsInSystem());

        //Reading SystemValues
        SystemValueList sysValList = new SystemValueList(as400);
        Vector<SystemValue> sysValVec = new Vector<SystemValue>();
        sysValVec = sysValList.getGroup(SystemValueList.GROUP_ALL);

        System.out.println("<<<<  SystemValues >>>>");
        for (SystemValue systemValue : sysValVec) {
            String sysValName = systemValue.getName();
            systemValue.getValue();
            System.out.println("Value: " + sysValName + " - " + systemValue.getValue());
        }
        System.out.println("<<<<  SystemValues >>>>");
    }
```

I already read a lot of documentation but was not able to find anything.

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_71/rzahh/as400obj.htm
http://itknowledgeexchange.techtarget.com/itanswers/system-information-into-a-file/
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ibmi/library/i-javatoolbox/

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think you're going to find that information.

IBM i Operating System, (aka OS/400) doesn't see RAM & HDD separately.  Instead, it sees a single large address space known as the **single level store**.

http://db2fori.blogspot.com/2012/11/one-of-crown-jewels-single-level-storage.html

Certainly the low level **Technology Independent Machine Interface (TIMI)** knows about RAM/SSD/HDD.  But that's buried deep.  IBM surfaces some of that information via it's own command such as

```
Work Disk Status (WRKDSKSTS)
               Size    % 
Unit  Type      (M)  Used
   1  4327    52923  68.9
   2  4327    52923  68.9
```

But memory is basically always 100% used.  The system basically treats all RAM as a cache for objects from auxiliary (SSD/HDD)  storage.

Comment: Thank you very much for this detailed answer.

Comment: Kind of depends on how your memory pools are defined, but the general idea of "RAM equals (a HDD cache)" is a good way to keep it in mind.

Answer (score 3):

@Charles answered the question about RAM usage.

With respect to System Values, a System Value is a... configuration item for the host system.  An example is QDATFMT which describes the way a data is displayed, 03-31-2016 or 31.03.6, etc.  Generally, the System Administrator is most interested in System Values.  The Knowledge Center explains System Values: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_72/rzakz/rzakz1.htm?lang=en